# RadTabStrip - hide tabs client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

RadTabStrip - Need to hide tabs using javascript/JQuery dynamically on user selection from dropdown list box?
Used existing Telerik web site FAQ's but no succcess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var tabStrip = $find("<%= RadTabStrip1.ClientID %>");

var tab = tabStrip.findTabByText( "Paris");

tab.set_visible(false);
```

Here is a link to the article: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip-client-side-radtab.html